# PHP GD Image Countdown No Longer Working

Tags: php, image, gd

This countdown script worked for the last couple of years. Nothing has changed with the script, but time, so I assume the code simply deprecated.

Here are the different parts of the script:

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://example.com/countdown.php" />
```

**PHP - countdown.php**

```
<?php
header ("content-type: image/jpg");
$echo = file_get_contents("http://example.com/countdown-script.php");
$string = "".$echo."";
$font = 8;
$width = ImageFontWidth($font)* 48;
$height = ImageFontHeight($font);
$im = ImageCreateFromjpeg("http://example.com/countdown.jpg");
$x=imagesx($im)-$width;
$y=imagesy($im)-$height;
$background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 250, 84, 5);
$border = 5;
imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y,  $string, $text_color);
imagejpeg ($im, '', 100);
?>
```

**PHP - countdown-script.php**

```
<?php
countdown(2012,10,31,0,0,0);
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second)
{
$the_countdown_date = gmmktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
$today = time();
$difference = $the_countdown_date - $today;
if ($difference < 0) $difference = 0;
$days_left = floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes_left = floor(($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60)/60);
$seconds_left = floor($difference - $days_left*60*60*24 - $hours_left*60*60 - $minutes_left*60);
echo "".$days_left." Days, ".$hours_left." Hours, ".$minutes_left." Minutes, ".$seconds_left." Seconds Left";
}  
?>
```

Whereas it used to show countdown.jpg with the countdown in text on top, it simply shows as a broken image or defaults to an alt tag if used.

It works in my vanilla testing environment using PHP5.2, but I cannot get it working  over PHP5.4, apparently deprecated code for 5.4?

Comment: Have a look to your PHP error log. What do you see there? You may also save the broken image to disk, and open it in a text editor: the beginning of the image file is likely to contain PHP errors. (if any, the remaining bytes will be image data)

Comment: Not spitting out any errors. Looks like it's working in a vanilla setup. But, for whatever reason it's conflicting with some other script on the page, so I'll just use it on it's own unique demo page. Thanks

Comment: Scratch that, back to square one.